# CakePHP - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: php, cakephp

first excuse my english, i’m brazilian.

I’m creating an application in CakePHP and after using login authentication in CakePHP 4 it seems that my view doesn’t “run”.

this is the error: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUorU.png)

i using wamp64, this is my routes: [routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkHuy.png)

and i activated mod_rewrite.so.

Comment: check if files exists in webroot/css/ webroot/js/  webroot/img/

Comment: are you running the app in a different port than *80*

Comment: yes, files exist in  webroot/css/ webroot/js/ webroot/img

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2

Comment: Tonight I will work on the application, I will test it, thank you very much

Comment: The View is rendered (based off the image you shared). The issue could be that the path to your resources are not set correctly.